# Different results in Python and C++ when computing SHA-1 digest

Tags: python, c++, sha

I get different results when trying to compute SHA-1 digest in Python and C++.

Python code:

```
import hashlib

salt = 0xF0C020D239062F875C7BD8FB218D8102C9B37656F653E8DF0C655EF2D4A0CB61
password = 'pass1'

m = hashlib.sha1()
m.update( bytearray.fromhex(hex(salt)[2:-1]) )
m.update( password )

print m.hexdigest()
# output: e92f9504b2d46db0af7732c6e89e0260e63ae9b8
```

I extracted from the C++ code a snippet:

```
BigNumber salt, x;
Sha1Hash xhash;
uint8 password[] = "pass1";

// salt is received from a network packet (32 bytes)
// 2014-08-16 16:06:37 --> salt=F0C020D239062F875C7BD8FB218D8102C9B37656F653E8DF0C655EF2D4A0CB61
salt.SetBinary(lc.salt, 32);

xhash.UpdateData(salt.AsByteArray(), salt.GetNumBytes());
xhash.UpdateData(password, sizeof(password) - 1);
xhash.Finalize();

x.SetBinary(xhash.GetDigest(), xhash.GetLength());
logdebug("--> x=%s", x.AsHexStr());
// output: E5B463090B335BBC734BD3F4683F310E87ED6E4A
```

How must I modify my Python code to have the same results as in C++?

Comment: your python code doesn't work. with `hex(salt)[2:-1]` you have a odd number of characters.

Comment: @Daniel: no, that happens to work, because in Python 2 the number is a long int and a `L` is appended. It is a *terrible* way to produce the bytes for the salt however.

Comment: A better way to define the salt in Python would have been to use `'F0C020D239062F875C7BD8FB218D8102C9B37656F653E8DF0C655EF2D4A0CB61'.decode('hex')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use different endiness in C++ and python. So you have to reverse the bytes of your salt in python.

```
import hashlib

salt = 'F0C020D239062F875C7BD8FB218D8102C9B37656F653E8DF0C655EF2D4A0CB61'.decode('hex')
password = 'pass1'

m = hashlib.sha1()
m.update( salt[::-1] )
m.update( password )

print m.hexdigest()
# output: 4a6eed870e313f68f4d34b73bc5b330b0963b4e5 <- the reversed of the C++ result
```

Comment: @Daniel: Thank you for the answer, it works, but why don't I have to reverse the password bytes, too?

Comment: @xkyve: endiness plays only a role at numbers, not at strings.

Answer (score -4):

SHAs are specifications, hence some initial state can be implementation dependent.

I suggest to use the very same implementation if you need to compare Python and C++ codes.

Comment: The C++ and Python version **both use SHA1**. Initial state is **not** implementation dependent.

Comment: I didn't know they used the same sha. My fault.

Comment: @senseiwa if that wasn't the case, then it would be impossible e. g. to identify pieces of data with different SHA1 implementations.